# How can i get the index of an value in array based on a value from another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Ok so have two arrays. The other one is 2 dimensional like so:

```
const locations = [
['London', 60.205490, 24.655899],
['Rome', 60.294411, 25.040070],
['Berlin', 60.262800, 24.824730],
['New York', 60.1698557, 24.9383791],
['Paris', 60.629951, 24.858080],]

const cities = ['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin' ]
```

How can i compare the two arrays to get an outcome like this:

```
const indexArr = [0, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Please, can you explain question a bit more. its confusing.

Comment: It's unclear what your asking ([How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) but a simple `for` loop would be a good start.

Comment: Your question is entirely on the title of the question, and in the question body you have a single array and zero explanation of what you need or what you have tried until now. Please, [edit] the question to make it acceptable by the rules of "[ask]"

Comment: its unclear but....probably something like this `let val = locations.filter(el =>  el[0] == "Espoo")`

Comment: `Array.findIndex()` or a combination of `.filter()` and `.indexOf()`. We cannot implement it since you only provided the array to search in. We also need the array containing the value to search for. But knowing of the existence of the above array methods should be enough to code it yourself. ps: `const indexArray = cities.map( city => locations.findIndex( location => location[0] === city ));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get result as following:

```js
const locations = [
['London', 60.205490, 24.655899],
['Rome', 60.294411, 25.040070],
['Berlin', 60.262800, 24.824730],
['New York', 60.1698557, 24.9383791],
['Paris', 60.629951, 24.858080],]

const cities = ['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin' ]

let temp = [];

cities.forEach(function(someItem, someIndex){
  locations.forEach(function(item, index){
    if(item.indexOf(someItem) >= 0) {
      temp.push(index);
    }
  })
})

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: This works thanks :)

Comment: Bro kindly upvote and accept answer.

Comment: Oh i'm so sorry! First time posting and don't know all the ropes